# Using SmtpClient to send a print document as attachment

Tags: c#, winforms, email, printing, smtp

I've been looking all over the net to attach a print document in an email using SMTP but unlucky couldn't find one.

```
printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

Here's my code for previewing the document , I have a extra method for placing all labels,images in paper.

```
 private void btnSendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Timeout = 10000;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myUsername@gmail.com", "myPass");

        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("myRecipents", "myRecipents", "Title", "Body");
        mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

        System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType();
        contentType.MediaType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;
        contentType.Name = "tange.pdf";
        mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:/tange.pdf", contentType));

        client.Send(mm);

        MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }
```

Here's my code to send email and attach document. But here the document attached here is located in my disk. I want to replace that with my print document/preview.

Is there any way to make that?

Comment: Print to a pdf file, using a pdf printer and then this will fit in the code you now have. You might have to install a Pdf Printer first.

Comment: So basically I need to save it in a disk using pdf printer?

Comment: Yes, that is the simplest thing that will work.

Comment: Im using Print Document. But I couldn't save it as pdf programatically. I dont want it to be prompted . it should be automatically save in directory if i clikc the button. is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+printdocument+pdf